# Creating a function that prints out multiple data-frames in r

Tags: r, function, dataframe, coding-efficiency

I have a function that I have written to create a simulation that demonstrates the central limit theorem. I'm not sure if its possible or if I am better off just making separate functions but currently it only stores that data frame containing the mean values of all the trials.

```
# create function to perform CLT simulation 
# where n = sample size, t = number of trials, pop = which population is being used, popmean = population mean, 
cltsim <- function(n, t, pop, popmean, popsd, poptitle){
 popsim <- data.frame()

  # Run the simulation
  for(i in n) { # for each value of n
      col <- c()
      for(j in t) { #loop through each value of t
          trial <- 1:j
          counter <- j #set up an egg timer based on whichever t value we're on
          value <- c()
          while(counter > 0) {    # and extract n samples from the population
              bucket <- sample(pop, i, replace = TRUE)
              xbar <- mean(bucket) #calculate the sample mean
              value <- c(value, xbar) # and add it to a vector
              counter <- counter - 1 #egg timer counts down and loops back until it hits 0
          }
          sbar <- sd(value) #calculate the sample standard deviation 
          col <- cbind(trial, value, sbar, i, j) #merge all info together 
          popsim <- rbind(popsim, col) # attach it to empty dataframe 
      } 

  }

  #clean up so just the finished data frame is left 
  rm(col, bucket, value, counter, i, j, n, sbar, t, xbar, trial) 

  #tidy up data frame in order to graph it 
  names(popsim) <- c("trial#", "value", "sdev", "samples", "trials")

  #view the rows of data in popsim data table 
  popsim

}
```

when I try to add any more code that requires creating datatables it doesnt store them, below are the blocks of code I wish to add to the function

```
g1 <- ggplot(popsim, aes(x = value)) + geom_density(fill = "#09AB30") + 
        facet_grid(samples ~ trials, labeller = label_both) + 
        ggtitle(paste("Demonstrating The Central Limit Theorem with Simulation using", poptitle)) + 
        geom_vline(xintercept = popmean, linetype = "dashed")

g1
```

and

```
#create data frame of simulated sample standard deviations \
sdmatrix <- matrix(unique(popsim$sdev), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
sdf <- as.data.frame(sdmatrix, row.names = c("t10", "t100", "t1000", "t10000"))
names(sdf) <- c("s1", "s10", "s30", "s50")
sdf <- t(sdf)
rm(sdmatrix)
sdf  

exvals <- pop1sd/sqrt(c(1, 10, 30, 50))
dfex <- as.data.frame(exvals, row.names = c("s1", "s10", "s30", "s50"))
names(dfex) <- "Predicted Standard Deviations"
dfex
```

Ive had a look around and I cant find a solution anywhere, am I better off just writing different functions for them? Any advice or input on how to make this lot of code more effective/efficient would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: A few notes: (a) `rm` is pointless inside a function. The only thing that persists after a function is the `return` value (by default, the last line of the function). (b) A `while` loop is great when you don't know the number of iterations. Instead of a `while` "egg counter", using `for(k in 1:j)` is probably simpler... or `replicate` since the trial number isn't needed internally. (c) Building data frames up one row at a time is **slow**. It's much faster to put the results in a list (or keep them as vectors) and put them in a data frame at the very end.

Comment: (d) Extension of (a), and very relevant to your stated problem: function in R `return` something, they generally don't make new objects "appear" in your environment. If I have `x = 1:10` and I run `mean(x)`, I see the result, but it is not stored anywhere. `mean` doesn't create an object named `mean_x` (or any other name) storing the result. Similarly, when you run `cltsim()`, it returns your `popsim` data frame (because `popsim` is the last line of the function), but unless you assign the result with `result <- cltsim(...)`, it isn't stored.

Comment: ...Functions in R can only return one thing. If you want a function to return multiple things, you need to stick them together, usually in a list. You could include the extra code in your function, and make the last line `return(list(popsim, g1, sdf, dfex))`, and your return value will be a single list containing each of those pieces.

Comment: *That said*, it's turning it into a very big function to add all those pieces, which can be inflexible and difficult to maintain. I think your life will be easier if you keep `cltsim` as-is, and make other functions to produce your other outputs, taking `cltsim` as input. Then you can make a wrapper function that takes all your input, and calls each of the sub-functions in turn, and returns all the results in a list. This modularizes your code a bit more and makes you more able to experiment with variations of one module or the other. It usually makes it easier to debug issues too.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas. Perhaps you could put all of that into an _answer_?

Comment: that was very helpful thanks, I'll have a fiddle around with it tomorrow and see how i can make it work. I thought it would be a bit too much for one function and was definitely leaning towards keeping them separate

Comment: @Edward eh, I feel like a *good* answer would incorporate all that into a rewrite of OP's function. I may get around to it if no one else does, but I'd be very happy for someone else to do it.